# What would happen if I set null in prepared statement with varchar always?

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g, prepared-statement

I have this method to insert data using jdbc that will insert the value according to the java type. Something like this:

```
Object o = map.get( key );

if( o == null ) {
    // setNull( index );
} else  if( o instanceof String ) {
    // setString( index, (String) o );
} else if( o instanceof Timestamp ) {
    // setTimestampt( index, ( Timestamp ) o );
} else if( o instanceof Integer ) {
    // setInt( index, (Integer) o );
}
    index++;
```

It has a problem though ( beside it is all commented :P )

If the value of **o** is null, I'm requiered to use ["setNull(int, int)"](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29) method, but **I have to specify the SQL type**:

> *...**Note**: You must specify the parameter's SQL type.*

But... I don't know the type, so I'm considering use always VARCHAR ( just because )

```
setNull( index,Types.VARCHAR); .
```

What would happen  if I set null in prepared statement with varchar always?

I'm using:

```
Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

With Oracle JDB driver:

```
11.1.0.7.0-Production ( ojdbc6.jar )
```

What would be an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Could you not interrogate the database and get the column type via the `ResultSetMetaData` interface?

Comment: It's a bit complicated. I'm fooling around with an extra extra dynamism ( sort of ) so I don't really have the exact position of the column. But instead I'm setting the position based on the column name ( like EMPL_ID may be the 20th column but I'm setting it like the 1st on my pstmt..... )

Comment: Wait, wait... it is starting to make sense.... mmmhhh .... let me chew it for a while... What if I do ( select * from table where 1 = 0 ; get the ResultSetMetadata and get the type using the columnname ... ( o no! I see another Map<String,String> in my future... ) ...

Comment: Can't you get as input the value and the type instead of just the value as you are getting now?

Comment: @OpenSource... I might, it's just the source is not a SQL table

Comment: Love the Map<String,String>s, Oscar. Love them like a brother.